# $G$ is connected, $T1$ and $T2$ distincts spanning trees. Let $a$ be edge of $T1$. Prove exists edge $b$ in $T2$ such as $T1 - a + b$ is spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having trouble solving the question:

Let $G$ be a connected graph, $T1$ and $T2$ distincts spanning trees of $G$, and let $a$ be an edge of $T1$. Prove that an edge $b$ in $T2$ such as $T1 - a + b$ is a spanning tree of $G$.

Comment: what have you tried? Did you try at least drawing a picture? Anyways please check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: A similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223093/let-g-be-a-connected-graph-and-let-t1-and-t2-be-spanning-trees-of-g-let-e-be-an?rq=1) from which the answer to this question follows